# Enable CSRF protection on GET request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, csrf, struts-1

I would like to know is there any proper way to enable CSRF protection on all `GET` request's of the application? at the moment I have implemented it on all `POST` request using `javax.servlet.Filter` and then enabling it inside the `JSP`'s `POST` methods hidden fields like this
`<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="${my_csrf_token}" />`

Did same for GET requests as well, appending the token to parameters like this

```
$.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Someprocess.do",
                type: "GET",
                data: {param1: request.param1, param2: "param2", csrf_token: "${CSRF_TOKEN}"},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
```

but it gets displayed in URL

`domain?params=params&csrf_token=token`

would much appreciate good hints.

Answer (score 0):

Your protection mechanism will depend on your authentication type. For stateful authentication you could implement JWT. If you only use authentication via Bearer tokens and not via cookies then CSRF vulnerability shouldn't be a problem.

If you want stateless authentication, then you will be prone to CSRF even with JWT token. You will need an information that isn't included in a cookie, some CSRF mitigation mechanism, for example you could use a CSRF token.

Comment: Hello @Aleksa i already have implemented it for both request `GET`, `POST`, what I'm looking for is a proper way of doing it on `GET` request, without displaying token in `URL` or in a `source` of the application.